# How to sort by a custom “text” date field in mmddyyyy format

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having issues sorting by a custom date field on my WordPress website. I'm not a WordPress coder by any means, and i'm working with a previous owner's code.

Basically the field is an ACF text field that a user enters a date into (mm/dd/yyyy format). I'm able to sort them, but they are sorting by month. How can I get these sorted by the complete date?

My code is below:

```php
    <?php // Get all amendments
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'court_order',
        'meta_key' => "date_signed",
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'   => 'DESC',

    )); ?>
```

Then further down I have:

```php
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>

                <?php
                    $file = get_field('file_upload');
                    $dateSigned = get_field('date_signed', false, false);
                    $dateSigned = new DateTime($dateSigned);
                    $dateEffective = get_field('effective_date', false, false);
                    $dateEffective = new DateTime($dateEffective);
                    $name = get_the_title();
                ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), for example:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $dateEffective);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Where would I put this code at?  I'm wanting to sort by the date_signed field.  I'm not a strong WordPress coder, so any help you can give on where to put this code would be great!